# the direction things were headed is alarming

Tags: prepositions

This is from [a *Washington Post* article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2022/03/04/russia-ukraine-internet-cogent-cutoff/).

> But she said **the direction things were headed** is alarming.

I think the part in bold should be changed to 'the direction things were headed **in**'

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, although it's a common omission. You could also say:

> The direction *in which things were headed*...

The other thing that is possibly incorrect is that they *were* headed (past tense), yet it *is* alarming (present tense). I would expect it to be either were/was, or are/is, unless the intended meaning is that what happened in the past is a present concern, perhaps because it was not deliberately stopped and could repeat itself?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Some phrases can **optionally** have a preposition when they modify a verb to convey a event detail such as time or manner:

- You should do it (in) this way.
- We arrived (on) Tuesday morning.
- Let's go (in) that direction.

The first two of these are quite natural with or without the preposition. "Let's go that direction" sounds casual and "let's go in that direction" might be preferred in edited writing.

"the direction things were headed" is a noun phrase with a relative clause. It implies *things were headed some direction*. Adding the optional preposition: "things were headed in some direction"; "the direction things were headed in" / "the direction in which things were headed".

[Google N-grams for head[ed/ing] (in) that direction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heading+that+direction%2Cheaded+that+direction%2Cheading+in+that+direction%2Cheaded+in+that+direction&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheading%20that%20direction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20that%20direction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheading%20in%20that%20direction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20in%20that%20direction%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cheading%20that%20direction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20that%20direction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheading%20in%20that%20direction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20in%20that%20direction%3B%2Cc0) shows that "in" is more likely to be included than omitted (in books), but both versions occur.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic form of this sentence would be:

> But she said the direction in which things were headed was alarming.[1]

---

***WaPo's approach***

Sometimes (especially outside of formal writing) we drop the introductory part of the relative clause. Sometimes it even sounds awkward to include the introductory part:

> That's the way [[in which]] the cookie crumbles.
> Wasn't that the decade [[during which]] the economy shrank?
> There are several ways [[by which]] you can accomplish your goals.
> I will go to every place [[to which]] you go.

That is what WaPo is doing:

> But she said the direction [[in which]] things were headed was alarming.

---

***Your approach***

We can postpone the preposition in relative clauses such as this one:

> But she said the direction which things were headed in was alarming.

We can then eliminate the relative pronoun[2]:

> But she said the direction things were headed in was alarming.

And, voila, we get your suggested revision.

---

To sum up: Both the Washington Post's version and your version are correct.

[1] I changed "is" to "was" because I think that that makes more sense.

[2] We can only eliminate the relative pronoun if the clause is restrictive and the preposition has been postponed.

Comment: Thank you very much.